# Creating or finding Fire Fly style for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, style, illustrator

Has anyone had success in creating or finding a firefly style file for ArcMap?

Also, has anyone had success creating this same style in Illustrator and then adding it to ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Esri Blog they have [free fire fly style files for ArcPro](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/mapping/mapping/steal-this-firefly-style-please/). I don't know, but expect they are not, compatible with ArcMap. I would contact the Author John Nelson he may know if such style files have been created for ArcMap.

Otherwise, perhaps start using ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think ArcMap has the graphic capabilities to render a firefly style (ArcMap has only basic symbology capabilities, no drop shadow or glow effect for exemple) that's why you find these style only on software based on newer tech like ArcPro or QGIS.

If you can't use one of the newer software you could do the opposite of what you suggest ie. creating your map in ArcMap and then firefly it in Illustrator (One may try to get a somewhat close result by going overboard with ArcMap symbology (like several copy of one layer with each their own symbology with varying transparency) but the result won't be that good and the time spend to set it up is not worth it)